# Asynchronous insert to MongoDB in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, insert, async-await

How can I make an asynchronous insert/update to MongoDB in C#?
What is the terminology for lazy-persistence?

- write-behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB inserts are by default kind of asynchronous since it's fire-and-forget. The error check is an explicit operation or you have to enable the safe mode on the driver level.
If you need true asynchronous operations: use a message queue.

Comment: Not sure that *"inserts are by default kind of asynchronous"* was true as of the time this answer was written. According to this [official blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-20-net-driver) from 2015, async operations were introduced only in the 2.0 driver version, which was followed by SO questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091922/understanding-the-changes-in-mongodb-new-c-sharp-driver-async-and-await).

Answer (score 0):

In caching world 'lazy-persistence' would be called write-behind. Check this out: [Cache/Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache)

Probably the easiest way is to use the C# async method calls. This will tell you how:

The code would look something like:

- define your own delegate:

  ```
      private delegate void InsertDelegate(BsonDocument doc);
  ```
- use it

  ```
      MongoCollection<BsonDocument> books = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("books");
      BsonDocument book = new BsonDocument {
          { "author", "Ernest Hemingway" },
          { "title", "For Whom the Bell Tolls" }
      };

      var insert = new InsertDelegate(books.Insert);

      // invoke the method asynchronously
      IAsyncResult result = insert.BeginInvoke(book, null, null);

      //  DO YOUR OWN WORK HERE

      // get the result of that asynchronous operation
      insert.EndInvoke(result);
  ```

Hope that helps.