# Understanding the changes in MongoDB new C# driver (Async and Await)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

The new C# driver is totally Async and in my understanding twists a little bit the old design patterns such as DAL in n-tier architecture.

In my Mongo DALs I use to do:

```
public T Insert(T entity){
     _collection.Insert(entity);
     return entity;
}
```

This way I can get the persisted `ObjectId`.

Today, everything is Async such as `InsertOneAsync`.
How would `Insert` method will now return the `entity` when the `InsertOneAsync` will be done? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's helpful to understand the basics of `async` / `await` because it's a somewhat leaky abstraction and has a number of pitfalls.

Essentially, you have two options:

- Remain synchronous. In this case, it's safe to use `.Result` and `.Wait()` on the async calls, respectively, e.g. something like

  ```
  // Insert:
  collection.InsertOneAsync(user).Wait();

  // FindAll:
  var first = collection.Find(p => true).ToListAsync().Result.FirstOrDefault();
  ```
- Go async in your code base. Doing it async is quite 'infectious', unfortunately, so either you convert pretty much everything to async, or not. Careful, [mixing sync and async incorrectly will lead to deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Using async has a number of advantages, because your code can continue to run while MongoDB is still working, e.g.

  ```
  // FindAll:
  var task = collection.Find(p => true).ToListAsync();
  // ...do something else that takes time, be it CPU or I/O bound
  // in parallel to the running request. If there's nothing else to 
  // do, you just freed up a thread that can be used to serve another 
  // customer...
  // once you need the results from mongo:
  var list = await task;
  ```

Comment: Using MongoDB synchronously would be like calling an SQL database with a classic ASP application ? Would it lock the entire website until the call is over ?

Comment: Do you need to add something specific to make the `await task` line work? It keeps yelling that `await` needs to be done on something `async`.. but of course it is, since `.ToListAsync()` is there. Any idea what could be the issue?? @mnemosyn

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: `await` can only be used from methods that are declared `async`.

Comment: I typically use Mongo with Node/mongoose so it just seems strange to me here in the C# world. I tried `async Task FooAsync(IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection)` as a method and that worked. Thanks. I suppose chaining them inside of each other is the next part that's going to confuse me... haha

Comment: Async/await should be pretty close to what node does... Anyway, I suggest you step back a bit and start with a little trivial async console application that doesn't use an async library... Also, `IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>` doesn't look good to me (why not strongly typed?) But that leads too far from the original question...

Answer (score 0):

In my case: When I got this error:

> The source IQueryable doesn't implement
>   IAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that
>   implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework
>   asynchronous operations.

I have implemented the async where function for mongodb as follows.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Where(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression = null)
{
     return await context.GetCollection<TEntity>(typeof(TEntity).Name, expression).Result.ToListAsync();
}
```